# How to "get around" steam login while using HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, htmlunit, steam

I want to write a java program which can browse webpage associated with [steam](http://store.steampowered.com/). The problem is that I don't understand how steam automatically logs in users.

I figured these services use some kind of a cookies, but i couldn't find those cookies in chrome cookie manager. So even if I write a program which clicks the login button, then goes to the login page there fills it out, the secure page comes up which asks for email confirmation, which I can't and don't want to program. 
These sites are [tf2outpost.com](http://tf2outpost.com) and [backpack.tf](http://backpack.tf).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is an error with the website.

1. Go to http://www.tf2outpost.com/ with real browser
2. Click on 'Sign in through STEAM'
3. Check the source of the login page, at line #51 there is:

```html
<script language="javascript">
    function Logout()
    {
        $('actionInput').value = 'steam_openid_logout';
        $('openidForm').submit();
    }

    >$J( function() { $J('#steamAccountName').focus() } );

</script>
```

The issue with `>$J`, which is incorrect JavaScript and is not tolerated by HtmlUnit.

To get around this, you can change the response as hinted [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse).

So you can have something like:

```
try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
    new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {

        public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
            WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
            if (request.getUrl().toExternalForm().endsWith("identifier_select")) {
                String content = response.getContentAsString("UTF-8");
                content = content.replace(">$J( function()", "$J( function()");
                WebResponseData data = new WebResponseData(content.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                        response.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusMessage(), response.getResponseHeaders());
                response = new WebResponse(data, request, response.getLoadTime());
            }
            return response;
        }
    };

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.tf2outpost.com");
    HtmlAnchor a = page.getAnchorByHref("/login");
    page = a.click();
    page.<HtmlInput>getHtmlElementById("steamAccountName").setValueAttribute(username);
    page.<HtmlInput>getHtmlElementById("steamPassword").setValueAttribute(password);
    page = page.<HtmlInput>getHtmlElementById("imageLogin").click();
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);
    System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

Still, here is captcha that came up.

Hope that helps.